# If statement does not print out the body when the condition has met

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I expect the output will be the string in the wordList when it matched the search before the for loop exits but it does not print out every time when the if statements met the condition.

search = "ABC" 
wordList = [["ABC", "123"], ["ABC", "456"], ["DEF", "123"]]

```
public void biDi(String searchWord, String[][] wordList) {
    int start = 0; 
    int end = list.size ()-1;
    String search = searchWord;

    int path = 0;
    for (int i = 0; (i < (list.size ()/2)); i++) {
        if (search == wordList[start][0]) {
            System.out.println (wordList[start][1]);
        }
        if (search == wordList[end][0]) {
            System.out.println (wordList[end][1]);
        }

        start++;
        end--;
        path++;
    }

    System.out.println (path);

}
```

Comment: You are comparing your Strings wrong. You need to compare using the equals method

Comment: Wrong string comparison, change it to .equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to use `equals` instead of `==`, using `==` on string compare reference, not value.

```
if (search.equals(wordList[start][0])) {
    System.out.println(wordList[start][1]);
} 
if (search.equals(wordList[end][0])) {
    System.out.println(wordList[end][1]);
}
```